# Export data from Flash to Sharepoint?

Tags: flash, sharepoint, export

I'm creating a Flash game that will be placed in a Sharepoint page. Is there a way to export data from the Flash game (ex: the user's score) to a different Sharepoint page? I'd like to display the high scores of different players in Sharepoint.

**Note:** I'm using ActionScript 2.0

So here is the sequence of events...

1. Player completes Flash game embedded in a Sharepoint page
2. Flash exports player's score to Sharepoint database
3. Second Sharepoint page displays top ten player scores from database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1- to add flash game inside sharepoint check the following article in code project
(http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SPFFlashMovie.aspx)

2- No need for using database you can use sharepoint list instead of database ,So you can talk with list using web service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists%28office.12%29.aspx

1. you can create new page after that you add web part that read from the list that you already filter it (top ten players score)

I hope that clear
Regards,